# Kendo dropdown list not working with jquery validation engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, jquery-validation-engine

i can't check validation for a kendo dropdownlist using jquery validation engine. if i click the submit button, which checking the validation inside the form's control. All fields validation is ok, but only kendo dropdownlist is not ok. please inbox a solution. Thanks!

```
<script src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/validation-engine/jquery.validationEngine.js")"></script>
<script src="@VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/validation-engine/jquery.validationEngine-en.js")"></script>   

 <form id="validateForm">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <h4>Products</h4>
            <input id="Category" type="text" name="Category" class="validate[required]">
            <select id="products" class="validate[required]" style="width: 100%"></select>
        </div>
 </form>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#products").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "ProductName",
                    dataValueField: "ProductID",
                    dataSource: {
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                url: "/Products/List",
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

       $("#Submit").click(function () {
              javascript: $('#validateForm').validationEngine('attach');
              if (!$('#validateForm').validationEngine('validate')) {
              return;
           }
        )};
```

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging.  The jQuery Validation Engine is not the same as jQuery Validate.  Edited.

Comment: Ok Thanks @Sparky !